# Sci-fi book in Cyrillic with a white monkey on a pedestal in a Martian landscape screaming a ray of ice

Tags: story-identification, books

I saw someone reading a book in Cyrillic. The cover looked like trashy or pulpy scifi. I don't remember if it looked old or new, but if I had to guess I would say it was from the 60s-80s. It had a white monkey on a pedestal in a Martian landscape screaming a ray of ice (or so it seemed).

I've done all the image searching I can think of. It's completely possible that the monkey wasn't screaming ice but was doing something else, but I haven't found anything that fits.

Comment: ^_^ Welcome to SF&F. Glad you could make it, assuming you're the same guy from eng-misc.

Comment: Hey there! That's some info already but it would be ideal if you could edit in whatever parts of the plot you can remember. Luckily, we have a [handy story-id asking guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) which might jog some more memories :) please add every little detail you could remember!

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe he only saw the cover of it, and never actually read it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots meh. What happened to reading over other people's shoulders in the subway? :(

Comment: Unfortunately I don't read Cyrillic, so I have no idea at all about the plot. Presumably a monkey was involved, but even that is just an informed guess.

Comment: How could you tell the landscape was Martian?

Comment: I remember it being a reddish, Martian-like planet? Might not have been Mars.

Answer (score 14):

Probably one from "Of Mars" book series by Edgar Rice Burroughs, author of Tarzan (also known as [Barsoom series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Rice_Burroughs#Barsoom_series)), the books that tie in with later movie made from the book "John Carter Warlord of Mars" called  [John Carter (2012)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Carter_%28film%29) .

Why it might fit?

"John Carter Warlord of Mars" story anthology came out in 1963.

It is very definitively pulp sort of book/novel.

It happens on Mars and it has white apes in it.

[image: white ape]

Some of the Martians in that book series have what are basically magical powers. Not white apes though.

The movie  [John Carter(2012)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Carter_%28film%29) , while considered a box office flop, [was very, very popular](https://www.indiewire.com/2012/04/yes-john-carter-was-a-hit-in-russia-heres-why-47806/) in Russia (the most populous country which uses Cyrillic alphabet), grossing 16,6 million USD during first 3 days of showing there. It is possible that somebody saw that movie and is now reading prequel books.

Full image here:
[image: Ape on mars]

Comment: I like your reasoning, but for the life of me I can't find a matching cover. I'm wondering now if it wasn't Cyrillic but was a different non-Latin script and I just ignorantly assumed that it was Cyrillic. Your 2012 timeline fits perfectly though, as I think it was 2012 in Paris that I saw it.

Is it a violation of the terms of service of Stack Exchange to offer to send money to the first person to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? It's an ape on a pedestal on a planet alright but no ice screaming.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Engines_of_God

Comment: Nope not that one! Good guess though. That ape even looks like it's ice, too.